# Can a OCS 2007 R2 mediation server be installed on a front end server?

Tags: windows, voip, unified-communications, ms-office-communicator

Is it possible to install the mediation server component of Office Communication Server 2007 R2 on to the same hardware as the front end server component, or do I need additional hardware?

If it is possible, what would be the user limit before the roles needed splitting onto separate hardware? (assume I'm using fairly good hardware, i.e. Fast Xeon CPUs, lots of memory, 64 bit Windows 2008).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after much digging, and the answer is no. The mediation server can not co-exist with other components of OCS.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425201(office.13).aspx